# Remove DataRow from DataTable also removes it from an external List

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have this code in C#:

```
//newrow is contained in Datatable Data
//Selected _Rows is a List<DataRow>
Selected_Rows.Add(newrow);
.
. //Do stuff
.
foreach (DataRow row in Selected_Rows.ToArray())
{
    ...
    //This action also removes row from Selected_Rows. ???
    Data.Rows.Remove(row); 
    ...
}
```

I can't understand why removing the row from the `DataTable` also removes it from the list. Indeed, I needed to use `Selected_Rows.ToArray()` in the `foreach` loop to avoid modifying the list while iterating.

Comment: show your selected rows construction here.

Comment: The construction is `private List<DataRow> Selected_Rows = new List<DataRow>(); ` It is never assigned to `Data.Rows`. They are different objects

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: the DataTable was used in a DataGrid. And this Datagrid executes a Command every time the UI selection changes.

This code,

```
Data.Rows.Remove(row);
```

Modifies the DataTable binded in the Datagrid and the Selection in the UI is also modified. So, the Command is executed and produces the change. I didnt realize that modifying the DataTable I was also updating the UI selection.